# Halcon - verify if region is empty

Tags: region, is-empty, halcon

This row:

`intersection(CurrentZplaneTransRegion, Unshifted, CurrentRegion)`

sometimes returns a empty region. I need to catch this situation. How can I verify if the `currentRegion` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities for this.

First:

```
area_center (CurrentRegion, AreaCurrentRegion, _, _)
if (AreaCurrentRegion==0)
    * CurrentRegion is empty
else
    * CurrentRegion is not empty
endif
```

Second:

```
gen_empty_region (EmptyRegion)
if (CurrentRegion==EmptyRegion)
    * CurrentRegionn is empty
else
    * CurrentRegion is not empty
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `area_center(CurrentRegion, Area, Row, Column)` for this and check the `Area` result if it is zero.